# Does Java wait for thread.interrupt() to finish handling InterruptedExceptoin before executing callers next line?

Tags: java, multithreading

If I have the following code, is there any possibility of running `doSomething()` before the `interrupt()` finish the execution of `catch InterruptedExceptoin{}` block in `run()` method of `sampleThread`s.

```
...
//codes
sampleThread.interrupt();
doSomething()
//codes
...
```

Comment: No. It just issues the interrupt and continues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, calling `interrupt()` won't wait for the other thread to do anything. It sets the thread's interrupt flag, and then continues with its own business, regardless of what the interrupted thread does or doesn't do.

But calling it "asynchronous" can be confusing. Sure, it doesn't block the current thread, but it's not co-operating with the thread either, expecting the other thread to do something specific.

Comment: Ok.Thank you. So it seems, it's not like an asynchronous call. I'll edit the question.

Comment: So, If I wand to guarantee that doSomethig() is called after handling InterruptedExceptoin() I have to use a while(!sampleThread.isInterrupted()){}. Am I correct?

Comment: @wmIbb no, you're not correct. There's no standard approach for that, because that's not something you usually do. If you want your current thread to wait for the other thread to perform some specific logic, you need co-operation between the threads. Why does your thread need the other thread to finish what it's doing before it continues? If there's a dependency between the threads, interruption is probably not the right tool for that.

Comment: After this interruption call, `sampleThread` should finish. That's why I call interrupt() (to finish the sample thread in interrupt handling). main thread cannot continue accurately with sampleThread running. Will adding while(sampleThread.isAlive()){} before next line of the main thread will work here then?

Comment: @wmIbb even if it did (it does) work, it would be a busy loop. Call `sampleThread.join()` instead.

Comment: Cool. will try. Thanks again.